# Adding all elements in an ArrayDeque Iteratively

Tags: java, iteration, deque

I have an arrayDeque of BigInts which I have implemented as essentially just holding strings IE `BigInt@Instancewhatever = "3476234236734567"`

I already have a method to add one BigInt to another which returns a new BigInt, containing a String of the sum of the two BigInts.
IE

```
   BigInt@1 = "4321"
   BigInt@2 = "5555"
   BigInt@Sum = "9876"
```

My question is how can I Iterate through this Deque and call add on the BigInts.

I was thinking of using a forloop on the size of the ArrayDeque, but ArrayDeque doesn't really have a `x.get(x.size()-1)` functionality to it like you could with a normal ArrayList.

Edit:For more extrapolation, this is what I am currently working with.
        digit is the List format of the string IE 
        `"1,2,3,4","5,5,5,5"` etc

```
public BigInt times(BigInt operand){

    List<Integer> a = this.getDigit();
    List<Integer> b = operand.getDigit();
    //sum left unused atm
    List<Integer> sum = operand.getDigit();
    Deque<BigInt> temp = new ArrayDeque<>();
    Deque<BigInt> temp1 = new ArrayDeque<>();

    if(a.size() > b.size()){
        temp1 = multiply(a,b,temp);
        //Iterate here?

    } else {
        temp1 = multiply(b,a,temp);
        //Iterate here?
    }
    return new BigInt(temp1.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayDeque<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`, hence you can use a for-each loop over it:

```
ArrayDeque<BigInt> deque = new ArrayDeque<BigInt>();
//populate deque

BigInt sum = new BigInt("0");
for(BigInt b : deque) {
    sum = sum.add(b);
}

//sum now holds the sum of the elements in deque.
```

This assumes your `BigInt` class has a method `add(BigInt b)`. Either you have implemented it, or perhaps you meant to use `BigInteger`, the built in class for large ints.

A more advanced way to sum up the elements in the deque is to use stream reduction operations and method references:

```
ArrayDeque<BigInt> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
//populate deque...

BigInteger sum = deque.stream().reduce(BigInt::add).orElseGet(() -> new BigInt("0"));
```

Comment: I infact have a `BigInt.add(BigInt b)` method implemented, which is different form the built in `BigInteger`. I have added a bit more information to my post so I don't know if that would change anything in your answer.

Comment: Your initial block of code is almost exactly how I got it to work. Thank you

Comment: If you did `reduce(BigInt::add).orElseGet(() -> new BigInt("0"))`, you'd perform one less `add()` call, and the `0` value would only be created if `deque` is empty. Also gives you the flexibility of doing `orElse(null)`, or `orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` (or simply `get()`), if appropriate.

Comment: Good call, will change.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayDeque` implements `Iterable`, so you can use the extended for-loop:

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (BigInteger value : arrayDeque) {
  sum = sum.add(value);
}
```